# Non-EU citizen married to British citizen, wanting to live in Netherlands

Tags: united-kingdom, netherlands, eu-spouses, non-residents, south-african-citizens

I am getting married to a British citizen in the next year. We have been in a relationship for 7 years and have been living together for 6 years. We are both living in South Africa.

We would like to move to the Netherlands next year after getting married. How does it work for a NON EU citizen, married to a British citizen, wanting to go settle and work in the Netherlands?

If that is, for some reason, not possible, what would the procedure be for me to relocate to the UK with him (and work there). He has a British passport and I have a South African passport and we both live in South Africa.

Thanks! :)

Comment: The supposed duplicate doesn't answer your question at all.

Comment: @user in what way does the linked duplicate not answer the question?